# Sails JS locals div id

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm trying to inject an id from a div into a locals code in sails js.   All i get back is undefined for my buttonId.

'''
function changeMarketImage(buttonId) {

```
<% Market.findOrCreate({ symbol: buttonId },{ symbol: buttonId})
.exec(async (err, user, wasCreated) => {
  if (err) { return res.serverError(err); }

  if (wasCreated) {
    sails.log('Created a new user: ' + user.symbol);
  }
  else {
    sails.log('Found existing user: ' + user.symbol);
  }
});  %>
```

}
'''

it works fine if i put a string in there,  but i'm trying to dynamically inject in my ejs file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: why are you using `<% ` it looks like you try to push dynamic value to code generated at different time

Comment: In Sails JS the html page can interact with the database using locals  <% %> tags.  I'm using this when i click on a div button,  it grabs the div id and pushes it into this locals function.   If that makes sense.

Comment: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals from this it looks like your code in <% is executed during rendering and it doesn't have access to variables that are injected during runtime. if you use strings this works because they are defined in rendering phase but buttonId is not available as variable at this point. Probably you need to find a way to communicate with server during runtime.

Comment: Great!   Thanks so much!  That really helps!